# How can I get the value of "i18nLocale" at runtime in an angular universal app?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Is there a way to get the value of `i18nLocale` value defined in the `angular.json` at runtime? This is how my `angular.js` language configuration looks like:

```
            "es": {
              "outputPath": "dist/browser/es",
              "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.es.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",
              "i18nLocale": "es",
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "warning",
              "baseHref": "/es/"
            },
            "en": {
              "outputPath": "dist/browser/en",
              "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",
              "i18nLocale": "en",
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "warning",
              "baseHref": "/en/"
            },

...
             "es": {
              "outputPath": "dist/server/es/",
              "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.es.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",
              "i18nLocale": "es",
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "warning"
            },
            "en": {
              "outputPath": "dist/server/en/",
              "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",
              "i18nLocale": "en",
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "warning"
            },
```

I have a script that serves some svg images, and I need to adapt the path depending on the language:

```
  getSvg(url: string): Observable<string> {
    const parsedUrl: URL = parseUrl(url);
    const filePath = join(`dist/browser/en`, parsedUrl.pathname);
    return new Observable((observer: any) => {
      const svgData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
      const key: StateKey<number> = makeStateKey<number>('transfer-svg:' + url);
      this.transferState.set(key, svgData);
      observer.next(svgData);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
```

So I would like to know the value of `i18nLocale` to update this path:

```
const filePath = join(`dist/browser/en`, parsedUrl.pathname);
```

Comment: How do you decide which version of the website to serve? You can use the same mechanism to provide a language value, that you can use in your components/services.

Comment: I compile the app into the different languages, which get saved into different folders. The server just serves the files of the different folders depending on the url... There must be a way to access this i18nLocale variable during transpilation, right?

Comment: Then you should be able to provide the language from ssr server based on that url.